# How Do I pass the Option description in Checkboxes to a webform result

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a 3-option checkbox built as follows in Drupal 8.

How do I pass the value of the option title selected by the user into the webform submission result?

For example in the below, if a user chooses 21, the result should show 21 in the submission result.

```
[] 21
[] 22
[] 36
```

Each check box is a node field fld1, fld2, fld3. I have got these displaying correctly but the result shows up as [fld1] for option 21

**Additional details**

Here is the raw source generated by the webform module. This is Drupal 8 btw.

```
choose_a_value:
  '#type': checkboxes
  '#title': 'Choose a value'
  '#options':
    '[webform_submission:node:field_fld1:value]': '[webform_submission:node:field_fld1:value]'
    '[webform_submission:node:field_fld2:value]': '[webform_submission:node:field_fld2:value]'
    '[webform_submission:node:field_fld3:value]': '[webform_submission:node:field_fld3:value]'
   '#required': true
  '#required_error': 'Please choose a value'
```

Answer (score 0):

It roughly depends on how you build that form element. Form API or Field API? Seems you are with Field API here. In general all you have to do is to provide an associative array for the options where key equals value.

#### Form API

Here comes a simplified example for Form API. You might want to use `$options = array_combine($my_array, $my_array);` to build the options array dynamically.

```
$options = [
  '21' => '21',
  '22' => '22',
  '36' => '36',
];

$form['my_element'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => 'Choose',
  '#options' => $options,
]
```

#### Field API

With Field API and the list field you have to build the associated array in the `Allowed values list` like in the following example. Simply divide key and value with a pipe character.

```
21|21
22|22
36|36
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the values are derived from node fields. I have added the source generated by the webform module to the question.